# Callback in closure function

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I want to call `onCallback` inside the closure function, Is there a better way? Thanks for your comments and advice.

```
$.A.commentForm = function() {
    var hasWritten = false;
    var that = this;

    return {
        init: function () {
            $('#commentWriteForm').submit(this.onSubmit);
        },

        onSubmit: function (e) {
            var $form = $('#commentWriteForm');
            e.preventDefault()
            $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), $.A.commentForm.onCallback, 'json');
            //                                               ^^^^^ how to refactor this?
        },

        onCallback: function (data) {
            /* ... */
        }
    };
}();

$.A.commentForm.init();
```

Comment: `this.onCallback`?

Comment: You can define objects as a named variable and the use it as `variableName.onCallback()` and finally return this object

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately `this.onCallback` did not work

Comment: @Rajesh so `$.A.commentForm.onCallback` is only way to working as expected?

Comment: Please check duplicate and try if it solves it. If you please share what approach you tried and is not solving your problem. As said by @JaromandaX, `this.onCallback` should do it.

Comment: @Rajesh Okay, I'll check if there is some bug in my code. Thank you for  information.